# VSCode 'Git Status' not same in WSL.exe (compared with powershell)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I switched the visual studio code terminal to the new built in Ubuntu bash shell via setting json entry...

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"
```

but when I typed git status is was not the same result as I see in the default powershell?
so those are out of sync for some reason.

Should I file a bug? why would that be? what should one do? the UI seems not to see they are out of sync either.

Comment: Any chance the `core.autocrlf` is different between Windows and WSL?

Comment: I did change this value to true in the repo folders gitconfig file and it did decide that the few files where not different. so thanks for that. [Although I am still concerned with that setting is not going to cause me a problem of some kind later.] I still have one file detected missing that includes 'colons' in the filename regarding an ipv6 zone file .rdns maybe I should gitignore it anyway. [I guess that is another question though.] Note: I've opt'ed for setting it to 'input'.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading a different `.gitconfig` when running `git` in WSL. The `.gitconfig` is located in your home directory, in powershell this'd be `C:\Users\My Name\.gitconfig` and in WSL this would be `/home/myname` in your WSL, which is stored somewhere in a state folder in %localappdata%.

Check for differences between the `.gitconfig` files, you probably have line endings configured differently, like jessehouwing suggested in the comments.

Comment: it seems there wasn't one in WSL home folder at all, so I added one with only the username info was there. It seems that autocrlf does not belong there as it is specific to the repo folder (no global flag). [see above comment's comment]